# Angular input[number] allow blank?

Tags: angularjs

Is there an easy way to have `input[number]` directive accept a blank value?

I basically need to an input that accepts 1 - 100 but also a blank value. Hoping there's an easy way to do it without making a custom validator just for this.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D this is the built in Angular directive.

Comment: Confusing question whats input[number]

Comment: @Dsafds: I'm assuming he means `input[type="number"]` -> `<input type="number" />`

Comment: Then his question dosent make any sense? @DMan

Answer (score 1):

`input`s by default allow empty values (given `required` and `ng-required` are not set):

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="100" ng-model="val">
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app>
  <form name="f">
    <input type="number" min="1" max="100" ng-model="val" name="in">
    <b>val:</b> '{{val}}' <b>valid:</b> {{f.in.$valid}}
    <button ng-click="val = ''">Clear</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```